# Jekyll Build leaves off end of Javascript file

Tags: angularjs, jekyll

Jekyll build is leaving off half of a line of code and then all closing brackets at the end of an Angular controller file, which then breaks my site because of syntax errors.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

file to be compiled:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {

  this.toggleClass = function(elementId, className){
    angular.element('#' + elementId).toggleClass(className);
  };

  this.scrollTo = function(id) {
      $location.hash(id);
      $anchorScroll();
      $anchorScroll.yOffset = 100;
   };
});
```

result after compiling:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {

  this.toggleClass = function(elementId, className){
    angular.element('#' + elementId).toggleClass(className);
  };

  this.scrollTo = function(id) {
      $location.url("/");
      $location.hash(id);
      $anchorScroll();
      $anchorScroll
```

It just cuts off in the middle of the line. The build completes and starts the server as usual. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: A repository url can help reproduce and spot the problem.

Comment: What if you add all this block to a separate file in the `_includes` folder, something like `app_controller.js`, and  then call it where you need via `{% include app_controller.js %} ` ? Might help.